# Why is [DataType(DataType.Date)] becoming a TEXT field with EF Core 6.0

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Why is Entity Framework Core 6.0 with sqlite generating a *TEXT* field instead of *datetime*?
I have to manually specify it via the column annotation.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime? LastRequest { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> #### 2.2. Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.